# Google Sheets collect data from two sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, split, count, google-sheets-formula

I have two sheets.

Sheet1

| Name | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Boots | 30 |
| Dress | 10 |
| Jeans | 25 |
| Shirt | 15 |
| Sneakers | 35 |

Sheet2

| Name |
| --- |
| Dress/Red |
| Jeans/Blue |
| Dress/Black |
| Shirt/White |
| Dress/White |

I want to collect data to Sheet3 using one formula (unique names that contained in Sheet2):

Sheet3

| Name | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Dress | 10 |
| Jeans | 25 |
| Shirt | 15 |

I've tried to make some queries but I don't have enough knowledge. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(A1:B, COUNTIFS(INDEX(SPLIT(D1:D, "/"),,1), A1:A))
```

[image]